# Creating a Dynamic views in Android inside cardviews (As in to add different phone numbers)

Tags: android, textview

> I'm trying to make a contact app which can create contacts and add it to the phone default database. Now the question I came across is, how can I add more text fields for the user to enter more numbers?

- I was thinking about using defined fields (like in android contacts) and on creating of the view, show user only one text field and hide all the others. So the user can add more fields by the 'add' button next to the view.
- Then the problem is, how to align them properly under the first text field if the user wants to use the third text field instead of the second.
- I checked this in SO [Android: Adding multiple Views to a Linear Layout dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172221/android-adding-multiple-views-to-a-linear-layout-dynamically) but I need different IDs to getText from different textViews.

Is there a way to do this thing I want to do? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you define all your views beforehand and then just adjust their visibility at the runtime? Make more and more views visible as the user demands it.

Comment: I had that thought in my mind but how to adjust the alignments? Like below this view and that view?

Comment: Do you need to dynamically adjust the alignments? Can't you predefine all the alignments when you are defining your layout?

Comment: But then won't there be any conflicts? Let's say we had `Mobile Number` as the first text view and `Land`, `Office` as 2nd and 3rd. So if the user wants to select `Office`, how can I bring it right under `Mobile Number`? Because we are defining "layout_below:" something and when that view is not there, wouldn't it make it overlap with the first view?

Comment: how can user select `office` if it's not visible yet? what i understand is : you first show just `Mobile Number` and an `Add` button. Then when the user presses `Add`, you show him the second field, i.e. `Land` and if he presses `Add` again, you show him the `Office` field. Then he can enter office field. RIght?

Comment: @Yashasvi you kinda cleared it! I can use a drop down menu right next to each text view just like android phone book and get the type from there. With visibility option, without adding views dynamically!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109273/discussion-between-yashasvi-and-blogger).